Centroid of a set of vectors comprising polyhedral vertices
Consider the constant-norm vectors corresponding to the vertices of a regular polygon.  The centroid of a set of these vectors, including duplicates (for certain $n$-gons belonging to the larger dihedral groups), can sum to zero.  For example, the three vertices of a triangle, or the four vertices of a square.  There is no constraint on the number of vectors in the set.
[Edit: It is not true for all regular polygons that a centroid of zero can be generated by a sum of odd AND even number subset of vertices.  Example: the square.
However, some regular polygons with an even number of vertices allow you to sum an odd number of vertices to reach zero centroid. Example, a 24-gon]
When we move to 3D, and use vectors corresponding to vertices of regular polyhedra, it appears that the centroid can only be zero for sets that have an EVEN number of vectors.  One can find this out by trial and error.  1st question: However, is there a proof?
2nd question: Are there exceptions for non-regular polyhedra, such as the Catalan solids?

I don't understand your 2nd question : All Catalan solids have an even number of vertices,  as is the case of regular polyhedra.

The question is about taking a set of the vertices, which includes a subset of the polyhedron vertices but can also include duplicates, i.e. including one vertex more than once (another way of saying this is that we assign integer weights to the vertices when computing the centroid).

If the vectors add up to zero, then they are not linearly independent, so you shouldn't be calling them basis vectors.

Thanks, removed "basis" from the question

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly (I don't quite know what you mean by "constant norm vectors" in this context). Is another way of saying it something like: "let $P$ be a polyhedron whose centroid is at $O$, and let $\mathbf{v_i}$ be the position vector of the $i^\text{th}$ vertex of $P$. If $\sum a_i \mathbf{v_i} = \mathbf{0}$, where $a_i$ are non-negative integer weights, then $\sum a_i$ is even"?

@Chris, maybe the "constant norm vectors" means all the $v_i$ have the same length. To put it another way, the polyhedron must be inscribed in a sphere (in such a way that all vertices lie on the sphere).

Perhaps this works: Center a sphere at the origin. Put a vertex at the North Pole. Put three vertices on the Equator, equally space. Put three more vertices on a parallel of Southern latitude, in such a way that the centroid of the resulting polyhedron lies at the origin. Then the vectors from the centroid to the three equatorial points sum to zero.

@GerryMyerson Your example relates to the second question. The set of vertices equates to a triangle in the equatorial plane plus a regular tetrahedron. The first question is still not completely answered. It is probably related to the fact that the regular polyhedra have even # of vertices, and certain mirror symmetry. But I don't know a good proof of the equation given in the comment by Chris Lewis

@MichaelT the equation there wasn't really to be solved - I was seeking clarification on what your question is. Again, could you explain exactly what you mean by "constant norm vectors"? I'm guessing that it's something like Gerry Myerson suggested, but I'm not sure. You mention Catalan solids in your question, but the vertices of these don't lie on a sphere so I don't see how you would consider them "constant norm".

@ChrisLewis I did not realize vertices of Catalan solids do not lie on the surface of a sphere.  The question I'm trying to answer is exactly the one you propose in your comment with the equation: for $\sum_i{a_i \mathbf{v}_i} = \mathbf{0}$ subject to $|\mathbf{v}_i|=$ constant, is $\sum_i{a_i} = $ even?  The integer weights $a_i$ are allowed to be zero.

Per the list here, there are only five convex regular polyhedra, the Platonic solids. It's easy to check that among these, the conjecture that an even number of vertices of a regular polyhedron is required to get a sum of zero is true.
Among non-convex regular polyhedra, there are four Kepler-Poinsot solids: the convex hull of each of these is a Platonic solid.
There are also five regular non-convex compounds of polyhedra. Four of these again share their vertices with Platonic solids.
The last, the compound of five octahedra, has the same set of vertices as the icosidodecahedron, and this is a counterexample to the conjecture.
This shape has $10$ vertices along its "equator" that form a regular decagon. Picking $5$ alternating vertices along this gives a centroid at zero.
A nice interactive model of all these shapes can be found here.

The icosidodecahedron is not a regular polyhedron, at least by the definition given in the link.  Can you extend your answer by discussing only regular polyhedra?

@MichaelT Updated. You'll find slightly varying definitions of "regular" but I've followed your list. I hadn't thought you were interested in just the Platonic solids (which is essentially what the list comes down to, as you can see in my answer) because there are only five of them - you could have just checked these! Have you considered the question in higher dimensions?

I did check, which is why the original question said "it appears".  However, I wondered if there was an alternative way of proving besides brute force.  While at some level "a proof is a proof", if there is some higher-level explanation, some valuable insights (and generalization) could be gained.
